# Ignore styles from outside the component

Tags: vue.js

I use my Vue component inside an existing page with some global styles for input elements.
Now I don't want them to affect the elements inside the component. How would I achieve the component ignoring stylesheats not included in the `main.js` file or included in the respective component?

Comment: you can use `scoped` style in your component. It will not impact other elements as it will be scoped.

Comment: @CreativeLearner I already tried sing `scoped` inside the components. But the extern styles still affect the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your single file component you can add **scoped** keyword.

```
<template>
  <div class="has-red-color">test</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.has-red-color {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

Scoped keyword just use this style when you add this component.

Comment: I already tried that. Also the styles I talk about ain't inside a component but a CSS-File in the root folder of the project itself.

Comment: If they are in the same page and you do not have component then you can add a class that overrides the styles that you don't want to and add that class to your inputs etc.

Comment: That's the only way I thought of, too. But it seems quite annoying to do that for every single class. 
Or I could transform it to a custom component. But that's some caveats for itself.

Comment: Or you can create some normalize style for the main class. If you class is x-input then you can create x-input{color: unset !important;} this way you do not need to add another class

Comment: All right, I guess we came up with some ways how to solve this! Thanks for the brainstorming. ;)

Comment: You're welcome, have a nice day.